# Attach external disks at particular position

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

By using this code i can attach disks sequentially.
device 2, device 3, device 4

But i want to attach disks for a particular position.
I want to directly attach 3rd disk or 4th disk.
Without upgrading the previous disks

## code

```
            for disk in external_disks:
                    obj = {}
                    obj['id'] = getDiskPriceId(client, disk)
                    #obj['id'] = 2277
                    #logger.info("disk %s size: %s --\n" ,(str(disk_num)), (str(disk)))
                    if  obj['id'] == "":
                            print("Invalid external disk size")
                            exit(1)
                    categories = {}
                    categories['categoryCode'] = "guest_disk"+str(disk_num)
                    categories['complexType'] = "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category"
                    obj['categories'] =[categories]
                    obj["complexType"] = "SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price"
                    prices.append(obj)
                    disk_num = disk_num + 1


            response = client.call('SoftLayer_Product_Order','placeOrder', {
                                      "virtualGuests": [{
                                                     "id":  id
                                            }],
                                      "prices": prices,
                                      "properties": [{
                                                       "name": "NOTE_GENERAL",
                                                       "value": "adding disks"
                                              },{
                                                       "name": "MAINTENANCE_WINDOW",
                                                       "value": "now"
                                             }],
                                      "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade"
                      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach directly to an specific position through the attribute **categoryCode**, following is the order:

> **guest_disk1**  for  Second Disk
>
> **guest_disk2**  for  Third Disk
>
> **guest_disk3**  for  Fourth Disk
>
> **guest_disk4**  for  Fifth Disk

Make sure that item prices have the categoryCode you need, you can verify it by using the method [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::getUpgradeItemPrices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/getUpgradeItemPrices) as following:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[deviceId]/getUpgradeItemPrices
```

Following structure about prices allows to attach disks directly to the Third and Fourth position.

```
prices = [
    {
        'id': 2299,
        'categories': [
            {
                'categoryCode': 'guest_disk2',
                'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category'
            }
        ],
        'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price'
    },

    {
        'id': 2288,
        'categories': [
            {
                'categoryCode': 'guest_disk3',
                'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category'
            }
        ],
        'complexType': 'SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price'
    }
]
```

In your code the **disk_num** value needs to be between 2 and 3 to attach disks directly to the third and fourth position.

**Note:**
If you want to change/replace disk by another one with more/less space, you only need to apply the same idea. Set the categoryCode of new disk with the same categoryCode value of current disk.

I hope this help you.